# How to map only a part (byte- or block-based) of a device file or regular file to a loop device?

Tags: linux, loopback

How can I create a loop device of an existing block device or regular file of size `z` so that a certain byte `x` (with `x > 0`) appears as first byte, `x+1` as second, etc. and a certain byte `y` as last byte (with `x < y z`). It'd be great if there was a solution which could provide subsets of a 1TB device image.

This is not about operations on file level (e.g. `mount -o bind`).

Comment: This smells like an XY problem.  BTW the device you mount must contain a valid filesystem.

Comment: @sawdust, right, I hope I removed the unclear parts or shrunk them at least. I found an answer which is using `losetup` with `-o` and `--sizelimit` options. If you remove the "on hold" status, I'll post an answer.

Comment: Please post an answer as you said. Leave me a comment and I will upvote it.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I don't remember, sorry - and I don't mean "but, maybe, if you give me an upvote, I might remember" ;) too much time has passed.